# PhpStorm / WebStorm color scheme - TypeScript / JavaScript - how to target injected service

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, color-scheme

I've just upgraded PhpStorm from version 2017.1.4 to 2017.3.4 and to my annoyance it has affected my color scheme. See screenshot:

[image]

See my injected classes? `_builderService`, `_loaderService` etc- both where they are declared in the constructor, and where they are later used in the code...

**They used to be yellow**!!!

Here's how it *should* look:

[image]

I've looked in the color scheme settings both for Typescript and JavaScript and I can't see any relevant option to target them to change the color?

The closest I can find is 'Instance member variable'- but it's not what I want, that's too generic. Like I say, I used to be able to specifically target injected services to color them.

Anyone...?

Comment: This is highlighted as expected in a default 2017.3.4 IDE installation. Try to switch to another built-in color scheme (Darcula) and check the coloring there. If it's working as expected - try to reset your color scheme to defaults

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Darcula- or any of the built-in colour schemes- have the same problem. I've reverted back to 2017.1.4 since I find this too annoying and the new version brings no discernable benefits as far as I can see

Comment: Update: Installed version 2017.2.4 and this seems to respect the colour scheme. It's 2017.3.4 that breaks it.

Comment: PHPStorm 2017.3.4 works as expected - it treats the fields created in constructor in the same way as the other fields, and colors them accordingly (using **Instance member variable** color preferences); in 2017.2, they were colored according to paremeters settings

Comment: @lena "in 2017.2 (and previous), they were colored according to paremeters settings" <- that's the catch there! Before posting this question I went through *every single option* in the color scheme settings and changed it it to see if it had any affect, and yet somehow missed this- no idea how. Thank you for the information.

Comment: So, basically, it's a bug. The thing is, *it's actually really helpful* to have injected Angular services colored differently like that!

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to get a better answer on this, but for now I've simply downgraded to version 2017.2.4 which I've found still respects the color scheme, allowing targeting of Angular injected services (though I still can't actually find the color scheme settings which control this targeting)

Comment: Have you tried this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html

Comment: Which bit are you referring to? As far as I'm aware I've been through every color scheme setting for Javascript / Typecript / Defaults (my Typescript fields are all inherited from Javascript. Javascript fields are all set independently and don't inherit defaults. Ergo Javascript settings are the only ones that are relevant here). Nothing targets those Angular injected services specifically, which is what I want.

Comment: As @lena comments; "*in 2017.2 (and previous), they were colored according to paremeters settings*". I find this more useful than coloring them as ordinary variables which they've now changed it to do. So sticking with 2017.2.4 appears to be the only solution at present.